# lightbox is not working in updatepanel + c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 thumbnail images as `asp:imagebutton` instances. These are treated as triggers for `asp:updatepanel` control on the page which contains an `asp:image` control. 
When the user clicks on the thumbnail, the image in the `asp:updatepanel`'s image control changes to the clicked thumbnail image. 
The users are also allowed to again enlarge the image by clicking on the enlarge button (this runs the `lightbox` function). This works fine.

**Question**
The problem is that the enlargement works when the page loads, however when the user select a thumbnail and then tries. The method (`lightbox`) does not work.

I have had similar problems with `javascript` functions and the `asp:updatepanel`. Has anyone else faced similar issues? If so, how do I solve this issue?

Comment: What it says? where is the question?

Comment: Post code? It's obviously not doing what you think or want it to do...

Answer (score 0):

Following javascript was defalut one, it work fine without `asp:UpdatePanel`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
     $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
  </script>
```

but it is not working with `asp:UpdatePanel` so there is the need to call function on page load and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function pageLoad(sender, args)
   {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
   }
</script>
```

Thanks guys for helping.

Answer (score 0):

A $ function (which is a DOM ready function) will be only be executed when the page loads for the first time. 
Any further AJAX call (which is a partial loading/rendering) will not fire DOM ready function. Which is the reason, you were not able to get it working.

In you case, this function binds your anchor link (button) with the lighbox behavior the first time the page loads. so, it works. The next time when you refresh the update panel (which is a partial render) the button is not bound to lightbox again. Unless this binding is achieved it will not show up.

Normally a script control is used in such cases to fire the event every time the control is loaded.
If you are not bothered here about segregating related objects, the solution like pageLoad is still fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script src="../slimbox-2.05/slimbox2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */
            }, null, function (el) {
                return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```